# Set the all the hostname in cluster.yaml for clustershell in linux

Tags: linux, cluster-computing

Currently I am applying the clustershell to run all node in one command in linux. My hostname are `HD-01.project.org, HD-02.project.org... HD-15.project.org.` (from 1 to 15). From this documentation, it says that to set the configuration, need to add the  hostname in `/etc/clustershell/groups.d/cluster.yaml`

Since this is the first time Im using the clustershell, I am abit confused on how to use the hostname and set it to all in that cluster.yaml file.

Is it this way?

```
all: 'HD-02.project.org[1-15]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
**all: 'HD-[01-15].project.org'**

based on similar python tools.

Comment: yes, thanks that works. i set the config at local.cfg.

Comment: Exactly, you can test it like this:
`nodeset -e HD-[01-15].project.org`

Answer (score 0):

You can expand it with `nodeset` to see the result:

```
$ nodeset -e HD-[01-15].project.org

HD-01.project.org HD-02.project.org HD-03.project.org HD-04.project.org HD-05.project.org HD-06.project.org HD-07.project.org HD-08.project.org HD-09.project.org HD-10.project.org HD-11.project.org HD-12.project.org HD-13.project.org HD-14.project.org HD-15.project.org
```